# Empirical Distribution Function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $T$ denotes a nonnegative random variable representing the lifetimes of individuals in some population. Let $t_i,i=1,2,...,n,$ denotes an ordered observed value. Then the **empirical survivor function(esf)** is defined by

$$S(t)=\frac{\text{number of observations}>t}{n}.$$

Consider the observed valus of $T$: $9,13,13,18,23,28,31,34,45,48,161$.

According to the formula, The values of esf for this data are given below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
t & 9&13&18&23&28&31&34&45&48&161 \\
\hline
S(t)&\frac{10}{11}&\frac{8}{11}&\frac{7}{11}&\frac{6}{11}&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{4}{11}&\frac{3}{11}&\frac{2}{11}&\frac{1}{11}&0
\end{array}.
$$

My question is: at $t=13$, the first individual with $t=9$ is died. That is, at $t=13$, I have actually $n=10$ individuals remaining. Then why doesn't the denominator (number of individuals) reduces with time in the formula of $S(t)$? Why is the calculation of esf  not like the following?

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
t & 9&13&18&23&28&31&34&45&48&161 \\
\hline
S(t)&\frac{10}{11}&\frac{8}{10}&\frac{7}{8}&\frac{6}{7}&\frac{5}{6}&\frac{4}{5}&\frac{3}{4}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{2}&0
\end{array}?
$$

Comment: For some purposes, I can imagine that your method might be more useful. Who knows exactly what was in the mind of the person who chose the definition in your displayed equation? In any case, I believe that is the equation in general use, so you need to learn how to interpret it.

Comment: @BruceET That is, my method doesn't violate any assumption of probability. But why did you say it might be more useful? Could you please add something regarding to interpreting the valuse?

Comment: Just speculating. I don't know exactly what you're studying or the  exact purpose to which the ESF will be put. I'm just saying your method isn't obviously wrong.

Comment: I am studying  survival analysis. The definition and the example is taken from page 26, chapter 2 of the book "Survival Analysis using S: analysis of time-to-event data" by Mara Tableman and Jong Sung Kim.The reference is https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Survival+Analysis+Using+S+Analysis+of+Time-to-Event+Data+pdf&btnG=

Comment: The survival function, by definition, tells you the probability that an individual "survive" at certain time point (i.e. the lifetime exceed that time point). It is unconditional and thus the denominator of the estimator should be using the whole sample. If you are interested in hazard rate, something like conditional on the lifetime exceed a certain time point, what is the probability of death at a future time point, then you may estimate it also, which should be similar to your method but taking the complement.

Answer (score 4):

**Comment.** The usual 'empirical CDF' (ECDF) denoted $\hat F_n(x)$ starts at 0 to the left of the smallest observation,
jumps by $1/n$ at each sorted observation, and ends at 1 to the right of the largest observation. The 'emirical reliability' or 'empirical survival' function
that I recall seeing is $1 - \hat F_n(x).$

You indicate your text uses S, which is similar to R (which came later). In R, one has the following:

```
x = c(9, 13, 13, 18, 23, 28, 31, 34, 45, 48, 161)
plot(ecdf(x), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Notice the 'double jump' at repeated observation $13.$

This method refers to all $n$ subjects subjects throughout. Your method
seems to look only at the remaining survivors at each step. You might ask
your instructor whether your method is in use.

I don't have my survival
analysis book at hand and don't want to risk "telling you more than I know"
without a review of this topic. Maybe someone else has insights to offer.